# Choosing a buffer size for a WebSocket response

Tags: c#, json, websocket, buffer, clientwebsocket

I'm writing a C# application that connects to a websocket server, and receives a JSON response of unknown size. I'm using the [`ClientWebSocket`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket(v=vs.110).aspx) class for this purpose.

The only way to receive data from the client seems to be with the `ReceiveAsync` method, which takes an `ArraySegment<byte>` as an argument:

```
var client = new ClientWebSocket();
client.ConnectAsync(new Uri($"ws://localhost:{port}"), token).Wait();
var result = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1000]);
client.ReceiveAsync(result, token).Wait();
```

The problem is, since I don't know how big the JSON response will be, I don't know how big to make the buffer backing that ArraySegment. In this case I've specified 1000 bytes, which is far too small, and the response is truncated. However I'm worried that if I set the buffer size to be arbitrarily large, (1,000,000 bytes?), I'll be using up more memory than I need.

**How do I choose a buffer size without knowing the size of the response?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I understand the API correctly it will give you the websocket message in multiple parts if necessary.

That means if the message sent from the server is 2048 bytes and you use a 1000 bytes buffer and do:

```
var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1000]);
var result = await client.ReceiveAsync(buffer, token);
```

Then in this first call `result.Count` will be set to 1000 and `result.EndOfMessage` will be set to `false`. This means you need to continue reading until `EndOfMessage` is set to true, which means 3 reads for this example.

If you need everything in one buffer and can't live with processing the message fragments individually you could start with a small buffer and resize the receive buffer if the result tells you that more data is coming in. Thereby you can also check that if a maximum size is exceeded the reception is stopped.

```
int bufferSize = 1000;
var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
var offset = 0;
var free = buffer.Length;
while (true)
{
    var result = await client.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, offset, free), token);
    offset += result.Count;
    free -= result.Count;
    if (result.EndOfMessage) break;
    if (free == 0)
    {
        // No free space
        // Resize the outgoing buffer
        var newSize = buffer.Length + bufferSize;
        // Check if the new size exceeds a limit
        // It should suit the data it receives
        // This limit however has a max value of 2 billion bytes (2 GB)
        if (newSize > maxFrameSize)
        {
            throw new Exception ("Maximum size exceeded");
        }
        var newBuffer = new byte[newSize];
        Array.Copy(buffer, 0, newBuffer, 0, offset);
        buffer = newBuffer;
        free = buffer.Length - offset;
    }
}
```

And of course you should also check the other fields in the receive result, like `MessageType`.

Comment: An observation that caught me off guard: The value result.Count for non-EndOfMessage chunks is not always equal to the buffer size. It could be smaller.